# Custom 'Smooth Shading' shorcut not working

Tags: customization, shortcut

I have added shortcut for smooth shading <kbd>]</kbd> and for flat shading <kbd>[</kbd>. But why its not working on the object.

[image]

[image]

I have restart blender hotkey is present but its not working on the object.
Any suggestion or help. Thanks

**Answer where to find the addon**
Go to Text Editor and press Ctrl+T and you can find the addon Is key free

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender doesn't currently support symbols for shortcuts. Try using a different combination with only alphabets and special keys. If you want to check for available keys, enable the "is key free" add-on from User Preferences and go to the tools shelf of text editor and you will find the add-on at the bottom.

Comment: i did not find the addon in tool shelf can u show me screen shot where its located

Comment: I got it its not working with just symbol i added ctrl+] and its working. Thanks

Comment: @atek If you have extra information *about the answer* then this should be an edit or a comment to the answer, not an edit to your question.